# How to link a profile image from media library to a user in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am having some trouble trying to accomplish the following:
I have already uploaded all my users' profile images in the media library and I have already created all the users I need. Is there a way I can use a WordPress function or Api call so that i can update a user with their profile image.

Answer (score 0):

https://wordpress.org/plugins/metronet-profile-picture/

This plugin does what you're asking.

Googled: "set user picture wordpress plugin"

(Edit) Additionally: If you can make a proper CSV with all your users and the URL of their picture, you could import/export them with this plugin also: https://wordpress.org/plugins/import-users-from-csv/

also: https://wordpress.org/plugins/users-customers-import-export-for-wp-woocommerce/
Use this to export your current users into a CSV file
Then manually edit the CSV export file with the correct picture URL for each user, then import that same file back (delete all users first)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did try the metronet-profile-picture but either i am not using it properly or i have to pay for a version to do what i want. In regards to import-users from csv, I went ahead and tried that but that just imports users without allowing me to map which i already have the users imported.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/users-customers-import-export-for-wp-woocommerce/
Use this to export your current users into a CSV file 
Then manually edit the CSV export file with the correct picture URL for each user, then import that same file back (delete all users first)

Comment: I tried that but after updating the user_url with the url of the image and importing. I see that url as the user's website url and not their profile image.

Comment: User URL is his profile URL, not his profile picture URL.

Comment: ya - in my case i just want to update just the user's image or avatar as they call it not the whole profile page.